# Javascript delete node from xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I have read lots of articles on this, but CANNOT get it working. This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx>
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="47.66094590" lon="8.857512470">
        <ele>401.00000</ele>
        <time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.66006430" lon="8.858885760">
        <ele>406.00000</ele>
        <time>2010-01-01T00:00:51Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.65942840" lon="8.859422200">
        <ele>407.00000</ele>
        <time>2010-01-01T00:01:20Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.65913930" lon="8.859529490">
        <ele>407.00000</ele>
        <time>2010-01-01T00:01:32Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.65749170" lon="8.858370780">
        <ele>403.00000</ele>
        <time>2010-01-01T00:02:45Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.65779520" lon="8.857276430">
        <ele>400.00000</ele>
        <time>2010-01-01T00:03:17Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

I need to delete certain trkpt nodes (including the attributes and attribute values (lat and lon) and child nodes (ele and time) - the complete trkpt node.

This is my code. The whole xml file is called gpxDoc. The node which needs deleting is node p

```
trkseg = gpxDoc.querySelectorAll("trkseg");
trkPoints = trkseg[0].querySelectorAll("trkpt");

for (p = 0; p < trkPoints.length - 2; p++) {
    // Some code to check what if the node needs deleting
    if (offset > offsetLimit) { // needs deleting
        x = gpxDoc.getElementsByTagName("trkpt")[p];
        x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
    }
}
```

But it does not delete the node. Any ideas?

Added comments:
I added the following console log lines

```
console.log(trkPoints.length); // length is shown as 149 nodes
var x = gpxDoc.getElementsByTagName("trkpt")[p + 1];
console.log(x);
x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
console.log(trkPoints.length); // length is shown as 149 nodes
```

The console.log(x) line shows the trkpt node

```
<trkpt lat="46.966666" lon="9.50393434">
<ele>1242.0000</ele>
<time>2010-01-01T00</time>
</trkpt>
```

Comment: How can you tell it's not working?

Comment: Are you sure it is reaching the line `x.parentNode.removeChild(x);`? If so, console log and verify  `x` has right value

Comment: I can tell its not working by looking at the console. Please see the updated text above to see what console.log lines I added. Thanks...

Comment: What are `offset` and `offsetLimit`?

Comment: offset and offsetLimit are simply the criteria as to whether or not delete the trkpt node